# How can catch the error info when psql command embedded in python code?

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch, psql

The data can be imported in bash console:

```
psql -U postgres -d sample -c "copy data(f1,f2) from '/tmp/data.txt'  with delimiter ',' "
Pager usage is off.
Timing is on.
COPY 1
Time: 9.573 ms
```

I remove `with delimiter` clause to create an error:

```
psql -U postgres -d sample -c "copy data(f1,f2) from '/tmp/data.txt'  "
Pager usage is off.
Timing is on.
ERROR:  missing data for column "f2"
CONTEXT:  COPY data, line 1: ""x1","y1""
Time: 0.318 ms
```

All the error info shown on the bash console,i want to catch the error info when psql command embedded in python code:

```
import os 
import logging
logging_file = '/tmp/log.txt' 
logging.basicConfig(filename=logging_file,level=logging.INFO,filemode='a+')
logger = logging.getLogger("import_data")

sql_string ="""
psql -U postgres -d sample -c "copy data(f1,f2) from '/tmp/data.txt'  " 
"""

try:
    os.system(sql_string)
except Exception as e:
    logger.info(e)
```

Why the error info can't be written into the log file `/tmp/log.txt`?How can catch the error info when psql command embedded in python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the error produced by `os.system()` is not being captured by the try-block. `os.system()` can raise an `OSError` if the command fails, but it is possible that the error is not being raised and caught by the try block.

You can use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system()` to run the command and capture the output and error streams

Try this code:

```
import logging
import subprocess
sql_string = """ psql -U postgres -d sample -c "copy data(f1,f2) from '/tmp/data.txt'  " """
logging_file = './log.txt'
logging.basicConfig(filename=logging_file, level=logging.DEBUG, filemode='a+')
try:
    result = subprocess.run(['psql', '-U', 'postgres', '-d', 'sample', '-c', 'copy data(f1,f2) from \'/tmp/data.txt\''],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if result.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception(result.stderr.decode('utf-8'))
except Exception as e:
    logging.info(e)
    # The below line will help to get traceback of exception.
    # logging.exception(e)
```